# Firebase Crashlytics shows crashes only from debug build

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I am trying Firebase Crashlytics. I set up it using this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Then I tested implementation on simulator using Test Crashes in debug and release buildTypes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash

But in console I see only crashes from debug build. When I choose release build in drop down, I see 0 crashes.

In `logcat` I see the next message after crashing **(in all build types)**:

`I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: 5A265C440009-0001-0E3A-7685F7DB472C`.

What went wrong?

[UPDATE] after debug mode enabling:

```
12-05 14:51:49.906 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/gralloc_ranchu: Emulator without host-side GPU emulation detected.
12-05 14:51:50.146 13234-13236/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 261K, 4% free 9691K/10055K, paused 0ms+1ms
12-05 14:51:50.146 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Settings result was: 200
12-05 14:51:50.146 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Settings request ID: e8411059b9619f4aab9d1da802350f42
12-05 14:51:50.146 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Writing settings to cache file...
12-05 14:51:50.146 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Loaded settings: {"cache_duration":7200,"settings_version":2,"app":{"update_required":true,"ndk_reports_url":"https:\/\/reports.crashlytics.com\/sdk-api\/v1\/platforms\/android\/apps\/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs\/minidumps","reports_url":"https:\/\/reports.crashlytics.com\/spi\/v1\/platforms\/android\/apps\/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs\/reports","status":"activated","identifier":"com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs","url":"https:\/\/api.crashlytics.com\/spi\/v1\/platforms\/android\/apps\/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs"},"expires_at":1512492710153,"session":{"max_custom_key_value_pairs":64,"identifier_mask":255,"max_chained_exception_depth":16,"max_custom_exception_events":8,"max_complete_sessions_count":4,"log_buffer_size":64000},"features":{"push_enabled":true,"prompt_enabled":false,"collect_analytics":true,"collect_reports":true,"collect_logged_exceptions":true},"prompt":{"message":"Looks like we crashed! Please help us fix the problem by sending a crash report.","always_send_button_title":"Always Send","cancel_button_title":"Don't Send","show_cancel_button":true,"title":"Send Crash Report?","send_button_title":"Send","show_always_send_button":true},"beta":{"update_endpoint":"https:\/\/api.crashlytics.com\/spi\/v2\/platforms\/android\/apps\/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs\/beta_update_check","update_suspend_duration":1800},"analytics":{"track_view_controllers":false,"include_purchase_events_in_forwarded_events":false,"track_predefined_events":true,"flush_interval_secs":120,"forward_to_google_analytics":false,"max_file_count_per_send":1,"flush_on_background":true,"track_custom_events":true,"max_pending_send_file_count":20,"sampling_rate":1,"max_byte_size_per_file":40000,"url":"https:\/\/e.crashlytics.com\/spi\/v2\/events"}}
12-05 14:51:50.146 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Build ID is: 3ac52db2-2457-4eb6-a146-635aa5dfdd56
12-05 14:51:50.186 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Server says an update is required - forcing a full App update.
12-05 14:51:50.186 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: App icon resource ID is 2131296257
12-05 14:51:50.186 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Manifest
12-05 14:51:50.186 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Strings
12-05 14:51:50.186 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Generating Crashlytics ApiKey from google_app_id in Strings
12-05 14:51:50.186 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Build ID is: 3ac52db2-2457-4eb6-a146-635aa5dfdd56
12-05 14:51:50.666 13234-13236/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 377K, 5% free 9752K/10247K, paused 0ms+0ms
12-05 14:51:50.666 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Sending app info to https://api.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/android/apps/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs
12-05 14:51:50.666 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: App icon hash is f7a38bdfc0d07bd7e80ff8dcc521a975058a0617
12-05 14:51:50.666 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: App icon size is 72x72
12-05 14:51:51.086 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Update app request ID: dbe5793c4fd4c471169f85a73a056b66
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13254/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Result was 204
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13252/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Answers: Analytics collection enabled
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13258/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Manifest
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13258/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Strings
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13258/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Generating Crashlytics ApiKey from google_app_id in Strings
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13258/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Answers: Firebase analytics forwarding disabled
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13258/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Answers: Firebase analytics including purchase events disabled
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13258/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Answers: Custom event tracking enabled
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13258/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Answers: Predefined event tracking enabled
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13255/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Beta: Beta kit initializing...
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13255/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Beta: Beta device token present: false
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13255/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Beta: A Beta device token was not found for this app
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Initialization marker file created.
12-05 14:51:51.096 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Finalizing previously open sessions.
12-05 14:51:51.106 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Closing open sessions.
12-05 14:51:51.106 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Closing session: 5A265C59021C-0002-0E3A-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:51:51.106 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting session parts for ID 5A265C59021C-0002-0E3A-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:51:51.106 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Session 5A265C59021C-0002-0E3A-7685F7DB472C has fatal exception: false
12-05 14:51:51.106 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Session 5A265C59021C-0002-0E3A-7685F7DB472C has non-fatal exceptions: false
12-05 14:51:51.106 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: No events present for session ID 5A265C59021C-0002-0E3A-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:51:51.106 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing session part files for ID 5A265C59021C-0002-0E3A-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:51:51.116 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Closed all previously open sessions
12-05 14:51:51.116 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Initialization marker file removed: true
12-05 14:51:51.116 13234-13271/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Starting report processing in 1.0 second(s)...
12-05 14:51:51.556 13234-13258/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Answers: Sending 1 analytics files to https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events
12-05 14:51:51.556 13234-13236/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 395K, 5% free 9846K/10311K, paused 0ms+0ms
12-05 14:51:51.696 13234-13258/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Answers: Response code for analytics file send is 200
12-05 14:51:52.116 13234-13271/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Checking for crash reports...
12-05 14:51:52.116 13234-13271/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: No reports found.
12-05 14:51:59.546 13234-13273/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Session started, time: 23739484
12-05 14:51:59.556 13234-13273/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/FA: Logging event (FE): session_start(_s), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_id(_si)=184663540899271272, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity}]
12-05 14:51:59.586 13234-13273/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-05 14:51:59.586 13234-13273/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11720000 but found 9256030
12-05 14:51:59.586 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs W/FA: Service connection failed: nk{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
12-05 14:51:59.596 13234-13274/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
12-05 14:51:59.596 13234-13274/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
12-05 14:52:12.736 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Answers: Logged lifecycle event: PAUSE
12-05 14:52:12.746 13234-13275/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 23227
12-05 14:52:12.746 13234-13275/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-05 14:52:12.756 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: onActivityCreated
12-05 14:52:12.756 13234-13275/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11720000 but found 9256030
12-05 14:52:12.756 13234-13275/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Activity paused, time: 23752679
12-05 14:52:12.756 13234-13275/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_id(_si)=184663540899271272, engagement_time_msec(_et)=23227, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity}]
12-05 14:52:12.796 13234-13236/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 352K, 5% free 9927K/10375K, paused 0ms+0ms
12-05 14:52:12.806 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 22K, 5% free 9914K/10375K, paused 2ms
12-05 14:52:12.806 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.875MB for 147468-byte allocation
12-05 14:52:12.826 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 14K, 5% free 10044K/10567K, paused 2ms
12-05 14:52:12.826 13234-13275/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-05 14:52:12.826 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Answers: Logged lifecycle event: START
12-05 14:52:12.836 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Answers: Logged lifecycle event: RESUME
12-05 14:52:12.836 13234-13276/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-05 14:52:12.836 13234-13276/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 23752771
12-05 14:52:12.836 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs W/FA: Service connection failed: nk{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
12-05 14:52:12.836 13234-13276/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_id(_si)=184663540899271273, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=DonationActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=184663540899271272}]
12-05 14:52:12.866 13234-13276/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-05 14:52:12.866 13234-13276/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11720000 but found 9256030
12-05 14:52:12.866 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs W/FA: Service connection failed: nk{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
12-05 14:52:12.866 13234-13276/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
12-05 14:52:12.866 13234-13276/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service
12-05 14:52:12.866 13234-13276/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
12-05 14:52:12.866 13234-13276/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service
12-05 14:52:12.866 13234-13276/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
12-05 14:52:12.866 13234-13276/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 0
12-05 14:52:13.066 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Answers: Logged lifecycle event: STOP
12-05 14:52:16.326 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-05 14:52:16.326 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1312180)
12-05 14:52:16.326 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics is handling uncaught exception "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=10" from thread main
12-05 14:52:16.326 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Answers: Logged crash
12-05 14:52:16.336 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Logging Crashlytics event to Firebase
12-05 14:52:16.336 13234-13277/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{timestamp=1512485536337, firebase_event_origin(_o)=clx, firebase_screen_id(_si)=184663540899271273, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=DonationActivity, _r=1, fatal=1}]
12-05 14:52:16.346 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: No log data to include with this event.
12-05 14:52:16.376 13234-13236/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 5% free 10139K/10631K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-05 14:52:16.376 13234-13277/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-05 14:52:16.376 13234-13277/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11720000 but found 9256030
12-05 14:52:16.376 13234-13277/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 3543
12-05 14:52:16.376 13234-13277/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_id(_si)=184663540899271273, engagement_time_msec(_et)=3543, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=DonationActivity}]
12-05 14:52:16.386 13234-13277/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13236/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 453K, 6% free 10123K/10695K, paused 0ms+0ms
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Closing open sessions.
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Closing session: 5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting session parts for ID 5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Session 5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C has fatal exception: true
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Session 5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C has non-fatal exceptions: false
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting SessionStart data for session ID 5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting SessionUser data for session ID 5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting SessionApp data for session ID 5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting SessionOS data for session ID 5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Collecting SessionDevice data for session ID 5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing session part files for ID 5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Opening a new session with ID 5A26B2A0019E-0002-33B2-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Beta: Beta device token present: false
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Manifest
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Strings
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Manifest
12-05 14:52:16.406 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Strings
12-05 14:52:16.416 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics completed exception processing. Invoking default exception handler.
12-05 14:52:16.416 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Attempting to send crash report at time of crash...
12-05 14:52:16.416 13234-13234/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=10
                                                                            at lr.f(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at dm.c(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.cantalk.application.DonationActivity$1.onProgressChanged(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
                                                                            at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
                                                                            at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
                                                                            at android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(ProgressBar.java:670)
                                                                            at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.trackTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:411)
                                                                            at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:349)
                                                                            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5541)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1912)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
                                                                            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5721)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2890)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2466)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2475)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-05 14:52:16.736 13234-13236/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 394K, 6% free 10113K/10695K, paused 1ms+1ms
12-05 14:52:16.896 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding single file 5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C.cls to report 5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:52:16.896 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Sending report to: https://reports.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/android/apps/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs/reports
12-05 14:52:16.916 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-05 14:52:16.916 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-05 14:52:17.176 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Create report request ID: null
12-05 14:52:17.176 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Result was: 202
12-05 14:52:17.176 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: 5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C
12-05 14:52:17.176 13234-13262/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing report at /data/data/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/fatal-sessions/5A26B2850090-0001-33B2-7685F7DB472C.cls
12-05 14:52:17.416 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-05 14:52:17.426 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-05 14:52:17.926 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-05 14:52:17.926 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-05 14:52:18.426 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-05 14:52:18.426 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-05 14:52:18.926 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-05 14:52:18.926 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-05 14:52:19.426 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-05 14:52:19.426 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-05 14:52:19.926 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-05 14:52:19.926 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-05 14:52:20.426 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-05 14:52:20.426 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-05 14:52:20.936 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-05 14:52:20.936 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-05 14:52:21.436 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-05 14:52:21.436 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-05 14:52:21.936 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-05 14:52:21.936 13234-13237/com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-05 14:52:22.246 13234-13234/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13234 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Are you able to share your app's package name? If you don't want to share publicly, email Firebase support and the team can help.

Comment: no problem, com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs for release and com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs.debug for debug version with working Crashlytics reports

Comment: Thanks. Can you enable debug mode for your release build, cause a test crash, and share your full logcat output on relaunch? https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash#enable_crashlytics_debug_mode

Comment: @Alexizamerican, please, see update

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I'm checking with the team on this one. Stay tuned.

Comment: @Alexizamerican any updates? You can write me email, to interact directly and prevent SO pollution.

Comment: No updates just yet. We're still looking into it.

Comment: we want to check our backend logs after you create a crash. Can you cause a test crash for com.cantalk.ruen.dialogs and share the logcat so we can lookup the crash session? If you're able to share your email address, we can debug this faster. Or, feel free to write into support@fabric.io and we can communicate from there.

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem. Can you please share some outcome after you communicate that via emails? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

One thing to keep in mind is that crash reporting might happen **the next time** you open the app, as stated in [the Crashlytics documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash#force_a_crash_to_test_your_implementation):

> When testing, reopen your app **after** pressing the button to crash it to make sure Crashlytics has a chance to report the crash. The report should appear in the Firebase console within five minutes.

That being said though, I also had to change the time interval for crashes from 60 minutes to 90 days to see the crash that was triggered 2 minutes ago. Not sure if the actual interval matters, probably more the fact that things get fully refreshed when you change the interval.

Comment: Same fix. I changed my date range and suddenly the data appears

Answer (score 1):

I thought I was having the same issue; crashes for non-debug package not showing. My problem was that the Custom time interval did not manage to include my crash. The default value of "today" did not include the crash (even though it was actually just triggered). Changed interval to something else (like Last 60 days) made the crashes show as expected.

[image: Default interval when logging in[1]]

Comment: Wow... just wow... looking at this for hours... -.-'

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                FirebaseCrash.log("this is a crash"));
                FirebaseCrash.report("any error logs or object");
            }
```

Comment: I'm about Firebase Crashlytics, not about Firebase Crash Reporting

Comment: Ohh sorry... Still you can try with this check if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG)